# Links to chat don't detect app in Windows 11 - "Looks like you don't have WhatsApp installed!"

Tags: whatsapp

Perhaps since Windows 11 upgrade the links to:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=XXXXXXX

Do not detect that I do have the whatsapp installed via the Windows Store so it wants to log again via browser.

Happens on Chrome and Firefox so I guess is a Windows Registry issue.